# AngularJs communicating to sibling component not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on an old project where I use AngularJS 1.x and have trouble communicating to sibling scope

**App.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'headerModule', 'dashboardModule', 'profileData', 'roiData', 'eventData', 'LocalStorageModule']);

// Use Routes to Header Changes
myApp.run( ['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', function ($rootScope,   $state,   $stateParams)  {

    $rootScope.$on('callViewEvent', function(ev, x){
        console.log("here"); //getting printed
        $rootScope.$broadcast('vv',x);
    });

}]);
```

I have a directive

**eventData.js**

```
var eventData = angular.module('eventData', ['angularPayments', 'ngFileUpload']);
eventData.directive('eventData', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {},
    replace: true,
    link: function ($scope, element, attributes) {

    },
    controller: function ($scope, $attrs, $http, $state, $rootScope, $window, $interval, Auth, Upload) {

       $scope.$on('vv', function(e, x){
           console.log("event called");
           $scope.viewEvent(x);
       });

    },
    templateUrl: 'directives/event/eventData.tpl.html'
  }
});
```

A controller module

**dashboardController.js**

```
var dashboardModule = angular.module('dashboardModule', []);
dashboardModule.controller('dashboardController', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, Auth, $state ) {
    $scope.childmethod = function(x) {
        console.log("click"+x);
        $scope.$emit("callViewEvent", x);
    }
});
```

I am emitting event from child to parent and then brodcasting into another child. Emit is working but broadcast is not working. That is the second event call is working

Comment: So you don't ever see 'event called' but you do see 'here'?

Comment: yes that is correct

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
    $rootScope.$on('vv', function(e, x){
       console.log("event called");
       $scope.viewEvent(x);
    });
```

Comment: I have tried this but doesnt work. 'event called' is not seen

Comment: Its something to do with child not instantiated

Comment: Can you see the directive rendered on screen?

Comment: No. So when I actually click on the button that calls the directive and go back to my dashboard and try again, I can see directive being rendered. But If i refresh and hit my dashobard again so respones

Comment: Hmm, seems you need to work on that, since a non-instantiated directive of course can't receive events! If you're stuck perhaps post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The component that listens for the event is either not being instantiated or it is instantiated after the event is dispatched.

For debugging purposes, add a `console.log` to the component:

```
app.directive('eventData', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {},
    replace: true,
    link: function ($scope, element, attributes) {

    },
    controller: function ($scope, $attrs, $http, $state, $rootScope, $window, $interval, Auth, Upload) {

       //DEBUG TIMING
       console.log("eventData controller instantiated");

       $scope.$on('vv', function(e, x){
           console.log("event called");
           $scope.viewEvent(x);
       });

    },
    templateUrl: 'directives/event/eventData.tpl.html'
  }
});
```

Be aware that the $scope event bus is deprecated. Using it will make migration  to Angular 2+ more difficult.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Component-based Application Architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture)